# How to find the distance of a point to a line (knowing all the points)?

Tags: r, matlab, coordinates, distance

I have a line made of two points BA and a point P. I would like to find the distance from P to the perpendicular of BA and to the parallel of BA. 
Do you know if there is any fuction aready doing it in R or Matlab??
I attacht a picture to make it easier to understand.

Sketch given as below:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The function coding is straightforward from the textbook formula.

```
dist_point2line <- function(P, A, B){
    dx <- B[1] - A[1]
    dy <- B[2] - A[2]
    numer <- abs(dy*P[1] - dx*P[2] + B[1]*A[2] - B[2]*A[1])
    denom <- sqrt(dx^2 + dy^2)
    d <- numer/denom
    inv_cos_ang <- if(dy == 0) 1 else sqrt(1 + (dx/dy)^2)
    p <- d*inv_cos_ang
    list(dist = d, parallel = p)
}
```

Test with the distance from the origin to the line passing by `(0, 1)` and `(1, 0)`. The result is `sqrt(2)/2` and the distance parallel to the x axis is `1`.

```
sqrt(2)/2
#[1] 0.7071068

dist_point2line(c(0, 0), c(1, 0), c(0, 1))
#$dist
#[1] 0.7071068
#
#$parallel
#[1] 1
```

Another example, taken from @[ThomasIsCoding](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12158757/thomasiscoding)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60940330/8245406). Note that the results are different, this one is right.

```
A <- c(1, 3)
B <- c(5, 10)
P <- c(7, 7)
dist_point2line(P, A, B)
#$dist
#[1] 3.224903
#
#$parallel
#[1] 3.714286
```

To see that this one is right just notice that the distance from P to the line segment parallel to the x axis is visibly around 3, not 0.8.

```
plot(1, type = "n", xlim = c(0, 8), ylim = c(0, 11))
points(P[1], P[2], col = "red")
points(A[1], A[2])
points(B[1], B[2])
segments(A[1], A[2], B[1], B[2])
abline(h = P[2])
```

[image]

## Edit

Following a request by the OP to have the function compute the distance parallel to the y axis, here is a new version of the above function.

```
dist_point2line <- function(P, A, B){
  dx <- B[1] - A[1]
  dy <- B[2] - A[2]
  numer <- abs(dy*P[1] - dx*P[2] + B[1]*A[2] - B[2]*A[1])
  denom <- sqrt(dx^2 + dy^2)
  d <- numer/denom
  inv_cos_ang <- if(dy == 0) 1 else sqrt(1 + (dx/dy)^2)
  inv_sin_ang <- if(dx == 0) 1 else sqrt(1 + (dy/dx)^2)
  px <- d*inv_cos_ang
  py <- d*inv_sin_ang
  list(dist = d, parallel = c(xdist = px, ydist = py))
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help! It works for the perpendicular to the AB line. Thanks a lot!

Any suggestion with the parallel to the X axis?

Comment: @DanielJaraCortina Done, sorry I hadn't noticed the second part of the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rui! As I comment to our colleague, parallel does not give the right result I guess. Where does it lie? Thanks in advance

Comment: @DanielJaraCortina You are right, the error comes from the term `dy/dx` is the formula for the inverse of the angle cosine. It should be `dx/dy`. Corrected now.

Comment: Hi Rui again. I am testin the results that I obtained. As example, I have the following points
A (105, 34)
B (82.5, 31.3)
P (105, 31.3)

I obtain
perpendicular =2.724797
and parallel to X axis =22.5 (?)

I plotted everything but the distances of parallel data are not right. Any suggestion? Am I doing something wrong? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You can try the code below, where function names `perp_dist` and `xparal` denotes perpendicular to AB and parallel to x-axis distances

## R version

```
perp_dist <- function(P,A,B) {
  norm(pracma::cross(c(P-A,0),c(B-A,0)),"2")/norm(B-A,"2") # use cross product of vectors to calculate the distance 
}

xparal_dist <- function(P,A,B) {
  AB <- B-A
  perp_dist(P,A,B)*ifelse(AB[2]==0,1,sqrt(1+(AB[1]/AB[2])**2))
}
```

**Example**

```
A <- c(1,3)
B <- c(5,10)
P <- c(7,7)
perp_dist(P,A,B)
xparal_dist(P,A,B)
```

which gives

```
> perp_dist(P,A,B)
[1] 0.6933752

> xparal_dist(P,A,B)
[1] 0.8333333
```

## Matlab version

```
function d = perp_dist(P,A,B) 
  d = norm(cross([P-A,0],[B-A,0]))/norm(B-A); % use cross product of vectors to calculate the distance 
end

function d = xparal_dist(P,A,B)
  AB = B-A;
  if AB(2)==0
    f = 1;
  else
    f = sqrt(1+(AB(1)/AB(2))^2);
  end
  d = perp_dist(P,A,B)*f;
end
```

**Example**

```
A = [0,0];
B = [6,9];
P = [2.5,2.5];
perp_dist(P,A,B)
xparal_dist(P,A,B)
```

such that

```
>> perp_dist(P,A,B)
ans =  0.6934

>> xparal_dist(P,A,B)
ans =  0.8333
```

## **Update (R language)**:

If you have `A`, `B` and `P` in form of `data.frame`, e.g.,

```
set.seed(1)
A <- data.frame(X = rnorm(5),Y = rnorm(5))
B <- data.frame(X = rnorm(5),Y = rnorm(5))
P <- data.frame(X = rnorm(5),Y = rnorm(5))
```

then you can use `Vectorize` over your data frames, i.e.,

```
dperp <- Vectorize(perp_dist)(data.frame(t(P)),data.frame(t(A)),data.frame(t(B)))
dxparal <- Vectorize(xparal_dist)(data.frame(t(P)),data.frame(t(A)),data.frame(t(B)))
```

such that

```
> dperp
       X1        X2        X3        X4        X5 
0.1916007 0.3101444 2.2245761 1.2821965 0.2617655 
> dxparal
        X1         X2         X3         X4         X5 
 0.5619376  0.3351336  3.2146859 19.9448870  0.3494685
```

## Update 2 (R version)

If you want to calculate distance parallel to y axis, you can use the following code (MATLAB version is similar)

```
yparal_dist <- function(P,A,B) {
  AB <- B-A
  perp_dist(P,A,B)*ifelse(AB[1]==0,1,sqrt(1+(AB[2]/AB[1])**2))
}
```

Comment: Hi Thomas! First of all, I would like to thank you about your time taken for this issue. 

I´m testing the code a bit and I realised that the xparal_dist couldn´t giving the correct distance. I´m comparing it with the base coordinates that I use A(0,0) B(6,9) and P(2.5,2.5). It gives back ans = 1.2500 when normally should be around 0.9, shouldn´t it?

Comment: @DanielJaraCortina Thanks for correcting me. I have fixed the typo in `xparal_dist`, please check it out

Comment: Thanks!! And I have I guess the last problem. I have a data.frame (A, B and P) of 550 cases. How could I compute this operation to every case? I am really ashamed that I am that Dummy. Thanks in advance again

Comment: @DanielJaraCortina Do you mean `A`,`B` and `P` are all data frames with 550 rows?

Comment: Exactly! P has 500 rows , B and A too. I am trying to compute perp_dist(P,A,B)
xparal_dist(P,A,B) for each case

Comment: @DanielJaraCortina You can try `Vectorize(perp_dist)(data.frame(t(P)),data.frame(t(A)),data.frame(t(B)))` or `sapply(1:500, function(k) perp_dist(unlist(P[k,]),unlist(A[k,]),unlist(B[k,])))
`

Comment: @DanielJaraCortina I have updated my answer so you can check if that is what you need

Comment: Hi Thomas. As I explained to Rui I am testing the results that I obtained. And I obtained the same problem.

 As example, I have the following points A (105, 34) B (82.5, 31.3) P (105, 31.3) I obtain perpendicular =2.724797 and parallel to X axis =22.5 (?) I plotted everything but the distances of parallel data are not right. Any suggestion? Am I doing something wrong? Thanks a lot –

Comment: @DanielJaraCortina Visually I got it no problem, since it is `105-82.5`, so the parallel-to-x-axis distance is `22.5`

Comment: Ok, I guess that I explained myself wrong and there is where the problem lies. I wanted to calculate the distances of P to the BA vector, first perpendicular to BA, which it does. Then the distance from P to BA but not perpendicular but parallel to the x axis. I am operating in meters as info.

Comment: @DanielJaraCortina Yes, what is achieved is the distances from P perpendicular  to BA and parallel to the axis (cross with BA). I don't think there is a problem in my calculation. Otherwise, what is your expected output for points A (105, 34) B (82.5, 31.3) P (105, 31.3)?

Comment: I am very sorry. As I said it was my problem that I planned it wrong. The parallel distance should be parallel to y axis. I just transposed x and y as I plotted in my board. I am really sorry

Comment: @DanielJaraCortina Could you update your post? Now I am completely confused by what you are exactly looking for....

Comment: I updated a pic with more info. I just planned the parallel to the wrong axis. Sorry

Comment: @DanielJaraCortina see my update 2 at the bottom of my answer, where `yparal_dist` is for what you want